# Find $c$ such that the test which rejects when $X>c$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing

Consider a random variable $Z$ having pdf $f(z)=\frac{1}{2} e^{-|z-\mu|}$ , where $z$ is real.We observe $X=max(0,Z)$.
Find $c$ such that the test which rejects when $X>c$ has size $0.05$ under $H_0:\mu=0$.

Now, we know: $P_{H_0}(X>c)=P_{H_0}(0>c)P(Z<0) +P_{H_0}(Z>c)P(Z \ge 0)=0.05$ 
Since $c$ is positive otherwise the test will have size $1$, so $P_{H_0}(c<0)=0$.Thus, we have $
P_{H_0}(Z>c)\frac{1}{2}=0.05$ which gives $c=\ln 5$.
But I am getting to know that the value of $c=\ln 10$. So, where did I go wrong?

Comment: $P(0>c)$? What is your random variable here?

Comment: @JimmyR. $\{\omega\in\Omega\mid 0>c\}\in\{\varnothing,\Omega\}$, so nothing is wrong with writing $P(0>c)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the partition $\{Z\geq 0,\,Z<0\}$,
$$P(X>c) = P(X>c,Z\geq0) + P(X>x,Z<0) = P(X>c,Z\geq 0)= P(Z>c)$$

Hence, you have that $X>c$ iff $Z>c$ (if $c>0$), so
$$P(X>c) = \int_c^\infty \frac{e^{-z}}{2}\mathrm d z = \frac{e^{-c}}{2}.$$

Comment: But why is the conditioning yielding wrong results?

Comment: Because $P(X>c|Z>0)$ is not equal to $P(X>c)$. You need to find the conditional distribution of $X|Z>0$. This is quite easy but it's one step forward and two steps back for this application: $$P(X>c|Z>0) = \frac{ P(X>c,Z>0)}{P(Z>0)} = e^{-c}.$$